# Should we prefer Boost or standard lib?

Tags: c++, boost

I'm reading Boost array  documentation and I see this line :

> If you are using C++11, you should consider using std::array instead of boost::array

I was under the impression that Boost, for its major libs, was always preferable to standard lib because :

- boost will never perform worse than the standard lib
- boost may provide more features
- boost is at last of equal quality than standard lib (people writing the C++ standard are active boost developpers/supervisors)
- major boost features end up in the standard lib a few years later

So am I right to prefer boost over stdlib ?

If not / more complicated, which of my assumptions are to be corrected ?

Comment: #2 is certainly true (almost anything "may" happen). #1 is unfounded, even if true in practice. #3 does not follow and is also subjective. #4 may or may not be true, but in any case does not mean anything in this context.

Comment: I have found that the compile time can be greater when using boost libs because of the number of compiler workaround files that have to be pulled in, whereas a vendor's implementation of the standard lib can be written just for one compiler implementation.

Comment: The main part of the statement was "If you are using C++11". That is key, as boost is a C++03 library at present. I am sure boost will develop some great new versions for C++11 and probably some new ones, so boost won't go away completely.

Comment: @CashCow that is not the case, unfortunately. Latest boost requires compilation as C++11 to unlock all features.

Comment: It doesn't surprise me that boost has C++11-dependent code already.

Comment: Your experience may vary. Some features of boost are slow and unmaintained. Some are great. Some have an interface incompatible with the std:: version.

Comment: #1 is just false: example: make_shared from VS has perf optimizations that Boost at the time didn't have, it might have been added later

Comment: "You ain't gonna need it"

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I think you should use standard lib when available because... it's standard and comes with the compiler. Besides, if you use boost you need an annoying external dependency.

So, my advice is: use std when possible. If you're writing portable code, that must also be compiled with old compilers, you can consider to use your own namespace (e.g.: cxx0x) that embeds std or boost namespace according to the compiler you're using (this is called **namespace alias**):

```
#ifdef COMPILER_HAS_CXX0X
    #include <memory>
    namespace cxx0x = std;
#else
    #include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
    namespace cxx0x = boost;
#endif

...

cxx0x::shared_ptr<MyClass> = ...
```

Comment: That is called a namespace alias.

Comment: by popular vote, your answer is accepted. Thanks !

Comment: It's 2013… time to acknowledge **`CXX11`**

Comment: It's 2014, so... CXX14

Comment: It's 2019, so... CXX17. Especially the `std::experimental::filesystem` in CXX14 is now available as `std::filesystem` in CXX17.

Comment: It's 2020, so C++20

Answer (score 4):

Taken from the [Boost](http://www.boost.org/users/index.html) people themselves:

> Why should an organization use Boost?
>
> In a word, Productivity. Use of
>   high-quality libraries like Boost
>   speeds initial development, results in
>   fewer bugs, reduces
>   reinvention-of-the-wheel, and cuts
>   long-term maintenance costs. And since
>   Boost libraries tend to become de
>   facto or de jure standards, many
>   programmers are already familiar with
>   them.
>
> Ten of the Boost libraries are
>   included in the C++ Standard Library's
>   TR1, and so are slated for later full
>   standardization. More Boost libraries
>   are in the pipeline for TR2. Using
>   Boost libraries gives an organization
>   a head-start in adopting new
>   technologies.
>
> Many organization already use programs
>   implemented with Boost, like Adobe
>   Acrobat Reader 7.0.

Comment: +1 I always prefer examples to plain words.

Comment: This is Boost magnifying itself. Not a good source for a comparison like the one the OP is asking. The fact Boost inspired some standard committee is certainly true. The fact boost remains the best choice even after a standardization took place is all another story.

Comment: I had major trouble with boost so many times. Unexpected crashing when switched to the latest version (but only Release build), low performance because you don't know how boost implements something and you shouldn't really care, etc... If you can live without it, stay away from it and your life is going to be slightly nicer.

Comment: So the Boost people themselves suggest using Boost is a stepping-stone to using future standard libraries - which, by now, are the present! So Boost says "use the standard" really.

Answer (score 2):

From my own experience I prefer to use boost for now. Maybe it's historical, but I found the STD attempts in TR1 that came with VC2008 had too many bugs, in spite of PJ Plauger's best efforts, he couldn't reproduce the quality of the peer-reviewed and checked code of boost that had gone through quite a bit of history.

Unless they can actually take the boost code and use it in STD, why would they reproduce it better? Of course sometimes they might, and really they should work together on it rather than against each other.

One thing I do now though is declare an alias namespace, usually called `spns` thus:

```
namespace spns = boost;
```

after which I can use `spns::shared_ptr` throughout my code (spns stands for "shared pointer namespace") and if we ever change to std later it will be easy to go to one place and edit just that line and the include.

When it comes to C++11, there are major changes to the Standard and boost's code is C++03. So now the tables are likely to turn for certain parts of the library. I reckon some of boost's fine libraries will become almost obsolete for C++11, e.g. nobody will use `boost::lambda` anymore, they will just use the new language syntax for a lambda.

So yes, when you move to C++11, it may be time to abandon parts of the boost library and use the new versions.

Comment: Is `spns` an abbreviation for Shared Pointer Namespace?  Do you declare a namespace alias per feature?

Comment: If they are unrelated it makes sense. For example you might use one library for smart pointers and the other for threads.

Answer (score 1):

The trend that I have seen in open source software developed against C++11 is to move API-compatible (subset of) features from STD to boost - because boost is available for non-C++11-compatible compilers where the std features are (obviously) not.

Good example of this is [mosh](https://github.com/keithw/mosh).

For API-compatible features, it's simply a matter of switching namespaces around. In fact, no reason not to make it a configuration option, if you can.

Sidebar: if you're linking against the latest version of non-header-only boost libraries, be forewarned that certain features are no longer available unless boost was compiled with `-std=c++11`. I ran into this recently with certain functions in the `boost::filesystem` API.

Answer (score 1):

If something can be standard let it be standard.
If something cannot, use the solution more standard as possible (and BOOST is designed for that)

Many standard library feature are taken from boost, that continue to exist to support application that where deployed when those feature where not yet been standardized.

Using boost for standardized feature is in fact a "look backward". Sometime necessary (may be the standard library specific implementation does not include all what is required ... it is typical to see boost::thread instead of std::thread on windows because of a std implementation not yet been ported by some compilers) but I would not make it a rule.

Comment: Ahem... There is no "god" to define what is standard over what. What is accepted as a standard is not always what is labelled as "standard" (everyone claims to be the standard anyway). Boost may very well be considered more "standard" (i.e. more stable, best known, more widely used and accepted) than C++ stdlib, hence my question.

Comment: In fact there is a "god": the C++ language has a specification that defines what the "standard library" must be and contain. The fact the standard may not cover certain problem domains or that certain implementations are substandard are other problems. But the standard C++ comes from a well defined ANSI committee.